# $X,Y,Z$ be real-valued i.i.d. If $X=U(Y+Z)$ where $U$ is uniform on [0,1] what is the distribution of $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider three independent identically distributed real random variables $X,Y,$ and $Z$. Assume that $X= U(Y+Z)$ where $U$ is a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$. Find the distribution of $X$.

Here is my attempt: Let $f(x)$ denote the pdf of $X,Y,Z$.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X=x) = P(U(Y+Z)=x)&=& \int_0^1 P(Y+Z=x/u)P(U=u)du\\
&=& \int_0^1 P(Y+Z=x/u)du\\
&=&    \int_0^1 \int_{-\infty}^\infty P(Y=y)P(Z=x/u-y)dydu\\
&=& \int_0^1 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)f(x/u-y)dydu
\end{eqnarray*}$

Therefore we have
$f(x) =\int_0^1 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y)f(x/u-y)dydu $
and I'm not sure what to do from here.

Comment: What does composition of distribution and random variable - $U(Y + Z)$ - mean?

Comment: It's hard to understand... You mean that $X/(Y+Z)$ is uniform ?

Comment: @mihaild: I think it's just multiplication...

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, a consequence would be that $X/(Y+Z)$ is $U(0,1)$

Comment: I don't think that's possible. That would imply that $P(X> Y+Z)=0$

Comment: It's possible if $X,Y$ and $Z$ are constant.

Comment: Is $X$ a continuous RV? If so, $P(X=x)=0$ so you’ll need to rewrite these equations. (It looks like you are trying to use the law of total probability for the PDF).

Comment: Why does $P(X=x)=0$ if $X$ is continuous?

Comment: @UnboundedDysfunctional loosely speaking, it is analogous to a point having zero length. I do not feel it is appropriate to in-full explain here in the comments a subtle point about continuous RVs but if you search the question on this site or on google you will surely find it already answered in detail. (By the way please use the @ followed by a username to make sure we get notified of comments directed at us, otherwise we won’t see them until we happen to check back this question)